# IPV4 Client to IPV6 Server Connection Problem

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ipv6, ipv4

I am new at IPV6 and I need to migrate my IPV4 code to dual-stack. I have two applications, one supports IPV6 (dual stack) and used at server side and the other one is IPV4 only client basically.

Note that, on same host, there are one server and multiple clients. Since the device supports dual stack, some closed applications have to use IPV4 only to communicate my server. Because of that, I am trying to use loopback IPs.

When I create a socket on server side for "::1" address, client cannot connect it by using "127.0.0.1" address. But, when I run the server on "::" address, client can connect and on sever side, I see the client IP as IPV4 mapped address (::ffff.127.0.0.1). But the thing is, **I need to run the server on "::1" address** because of some security concern.

Here is my code snipped on server side;

```
   struct addrinfo hints, *result, *rp;
   int rc = 0;
   int sck = -1;

   memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
   hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
   hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
   hints.ai_protocol = 0;

   rc = getaddrinfo("::1", "9999", &hints, &result);
   if (rc != 0) {
       goto fail;
   }

   if (!result) {
       goto fail;
   }

   for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
       sck = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, 0);
       if (sck == -1) {
           continue;
       }
       int yes = 1;
       if (setsockopt(sck, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) < 0) {
           goto fail;
       }
       int v6OnlyEnabled = 0;
       if (setsockopt(sck, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, &v6OnlyEnabled, sizeof(v6OnlyEnabled)) != 0) {
           goto fail;
       }

       if (bind(sck, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) == 0) {
           break; //Success
       }

       //Fail
       close(sck);
       sck = -1;
   }

   freeaddrinfo(result);

   if (sck == -1) {
       goto fail;
   }

   rc = listen(sck, 10);
   if (rc < 0) {
       //error
       goto fail;
   }

fail:

   close(sck);
   sck = -1;
```

and here is the client side;

```
    struct addrinfo hints, *addr_list, *cur;
    int retry = 0;
    int sck = -1;
    int rc = 0;
    int val;
    long arg;
    struct pollfd pollfd;
    socklen_t len = 0;


    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    rc = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", "9999", &hints, &addr_list);

    if (rc != 0) {
        printf("fail: %d\n", __LINE__);
        goto fail;
    }

    for (cur = addr_list; (cur != NULL); cur = cur->ai_next) {
        sck = socket(cur->ai_family, cur->ai_socktype, 0);
        if (sck < 0) {
            continue;
        }

        arg = fcntl(sck, F_GETFL, NULL);
        arg |= O_NONBLOCK;
        if (fcntl(sck, F_SETFL, arg) < 0) {
            printf("fail: %d\n", __LINE__);
            goto fail;
        }

        retry = 3;
        while (--retry) {
            //connecting
            rc = connect(sck, cur->ai_addr, cur->ai_addrlen);

            if (rc == 0) {
                printf("OK: %d\n", __LINE__);
                break;
            }

            pollfd.fd = sck;
            pollfd.events = POLLIN | POLLOUT;
            pollfd.revents = 0;
            rc = poll(&pollfd, 1, 100000);
            if (rc == 0) {
                //timeout
                printf("fail: %d\n", __LINE__);
                close(sck);
                sck = -1;
                break;
            }

            len = sizeof(val);
            rc = getsockopt(sck, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (void *) (&val), &len);
            if (rc < 0) {
                //fail
                printf("fail: %d\n", __LINE__);
                close(sck);
                sck = -1;
                break;
            }

            if (val == EALREADY || val == EINPROGRESS) {
                //connecting
                printf("connecting: %d\n", __LINE__);
                break;
            }

            if (val == ECONNREFUSED) {
                (void)poll((void *)0, (unsigned long)0, (int)1000);
            }
        }
    }
    freeaddrinfo(addr_list);

    if (sck < 0)
        printf("fail %d\n", __LINE__);

fail:

   close(sck);
   sck = -1;
```

It seems disabling "IPV6_V6ONLY" option is not working.
Also, I already compare "proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo" and "all" folders' content. They seem same (except use_tempaddr and mtu)

Please help me on that.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you have the server bind() to "::ffff.127.0.0.1" instead of (or in addition to) "::1" ?

Comment: getaddrinfo returns error like "Name or service not known". I also tried adding "AI_V4MAPPED" to hints' flag. Result is same error. My lo iface below.
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        inet6 fc00::  prefixlen 7  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fec0::  prefixlen 10  scopeid 0x40<site>
        inet6 2001::  prefixlen 32  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2002::  prefixlen 16  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 0.0.0.0  prefixlen 96  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 3ffe::  prefixlen 16  scopeid 0x0<global>

Comment: Create two sockets in your server, one bound to `::1` and one bound to `127.0.0.1`.  Then pass an appropriate `fd_set` to `select`.  Reading from two sockets is not much harder than reading from one.

Comment: No sir, I need an adaptive, dual-stack application solution. I gave a localhost example but I need to migrate all my applications to dual-stack logic and some of these apps are listening WAN also.

Comment: Doesn't the same logic apply?  Just create as many sockets as you need, each bound to an address you want to listen on.  Like I say, this is not difficult, once you have mastered the technique.

Comment: Another potential approach would be to bind to `::` and then after the `accept()` call returns, check the IP address that the client is connecting from (as written in to the `sockaddr_in6` you passed a pointer to in the second argument), and if it isn't located on the local machine, close the connection.

Comment: As you know, an interface can get multiple IPV6 addresses. Also, my device has multiple interfaces. Binding for each address will be headache in long period of time. So, I need to make "::1" IP work just like "::" for my dual-stack purpose (reply for Paul)

Comment: Jeremy, I am trying to implement the approach you mentioned as a backup plan but my managers are not happy with it. There should be some way. I mean, if I cannot connect a IPV6 server as a IPV4 client, what is the meaning of dual-stack. Maintaining IPV6 and IPV4 connections separately is not dual stack approach!

Comment: @dogusyuksel `::1` is an IPv6-only loopback IP. When using a dual-stack socket, you have to `bind()` it to `::` instead so it can bind to multiple interfaces, both IPv4 and IPv6. Binding to `::1` will only bind to a specific IPv6 interface, which will not allow IPv4 traffic. `127.0.0.1` and `::1` are not the same interface.  I'm closing this question as a duplicate.  The dup describes Windows, but the same thing applies to Linux too.

Comment: Ok I got it. Thank you.